# Find the smallest positive integer a for which there exists distinct positive integers $b, c, d$ such that $a = b^2 = c^3 = d^4$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This is a nice problem from BdMO. The problem is-

Find the **smallest positive integer a** for which there exists **distinct positive integers** $b, c, d$ such that $a = b^2 = c^3 = d^4$

I have tried by fixing d first, then trying to find cases when the equation holds. But I could not find the answer. Please help me to solve it. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check out [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 2):

$c^3=d^4$ implies that $d$ is a perfect cube. We are looking for the smallest $a$, ergo $d$ is the smallest possible cube. Since $d=1$ does not yield distinct integers, $d=8\implies a=8^4=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{4096}$